# How to have an imported module's type definitions recognized?

Tags: typescript

I have this piece of code in `module-a`:

```
// options.tsx
const config = require('module-b');

const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(
  config.ownershipOptions.find((option) => option.value === initialValue)
);
```

The intellisense in Webstorm complains about `(option)` not having a type and `module-b` was not written in TypeScript. So, I created an `index.d.ts` file in the root of `module-b` like so:

```
declare module 'module-b';
import { OwnershipOptions } from 'src/types';

export const ownershipOptions: OwnershipOptions[];
```

This works!

However, I wanted to convert `module-b` over to use TypeScript, so that the `index.d.ts` will be auto-generated. My tsconfig.json file is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "pretty": true,
    "target": "ESNEXT",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "ESNext",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    "checkJs": false,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "removeComments": false,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */

    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/@type"],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */

    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./index.d.ts",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

A `src/types.ts` file like this:

```
export interface OwnershipOptions {
    label: string;
    value: string;
}
```

A `src/index.ts` file like this:

```
import { OwnershipOptions } from './types';

const ownershipOptions: Array<OwnershipOptions> = [
    {
        label: 'Readonly',
        value: 'readonly',
    },
    {
        label: 'Editor',
        value: 'editor',
    },
    {
        label: 'Owner',
        value: 'owner',
    },
];

module.exports = {
  ownershipOptions
};
```

An `index.ts` file like this:

```
const config = require("./src");

module.exports = config;
```

Now, using TypeScript this generates the following files:

```
// src/index.d.ts
export {};

// src/type.d.ts
export interface OwnershipOptions {
    label: string;
    value: string;
}
```

There is no `index.d.ts` generated in the root of `module-b`, however, the intellisense does recognise the types from `module-b`:

```
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(
    config.ownershipOptions.find((option: OwnershipOptions) => option.value === initialValue)
);
```

but, it still also complains about `option` having an `any` type. Any ideas what to do here?

Comment: Is the imported module available, on NPM or otherwise, to view the source code?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Is there anythgin specific I can show that would help?